# Flutter - How to catch Image.network error when there is no image in the link

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

Can you help resolve how to catch the exception when the image does not exist in the url given in Image.network widget. I tried it with errorBuilder property..but still throws an exception.

```
       Expanded(
        child: Image.network(
         imageUrl,
         width: 50,
         height: 250,
         fit: BoxFit.fill,
         errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrack) => Icon(Icons.error,),
        ))
```

When goes to the image link that  throws the exception, it shows as below:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
   }
 }
```

imageUrl link is taken from array of data loaded from Firabase as below

```
 Future<void> loadData() async {
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
  try {
    querySnapshot = <gets data from firebase>
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
      arr.add(result.data()); //adds data into an array
    });
  } catch (e) {
      print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this in dartpad and it's working fine. It shows the errorBuilder widget.

Comment: I tried this in Visual Studio Code.. It throws this exception - type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast.. Any reason to this exception?

Comment: @TirthPatel I am very new to flutter. Can u say how did you try this with dartpad..?

Comment: you could paste your code in https://dartpad.dev by creating a new flutter pad. I used (`''`) empty string as an imageUrl.

Comment: Are you using Null Safety? I've not seen `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast` error before.

Comment: For this code,null safety is not checked. I think that's why when there is no image object in the url, it catches as null for the image url. Can you help me to check null safety for this case..

Comment: I have tried it in dartpad. It does not give errors but in visual studio code, this throws above exception

Comment: could you add more code? Is `imageUrl` coming from an API call?

Comment: Yes. imageUrl is coming from Firebase..

Answer (score 2):

You can use error builder as following

```
errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
   return Image.asset(
             'assets/images/image_not_found.png',
              width: 300, 
              height: 200, 
              fit: BoxFit.contain
   );
}
```

OR

```
errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          return Icon(Icons.error);
        }
```